# Does Haskell discard a spark when the thunk is garbage collected?

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing, ghc

For example:

```
x :: Maybe a
y :: a
y `par` x `pseq` (fromMaybe y x)
```

Is the spark of `y` stopped and discarded if `x` is computed (much) sooner and is `Just ...`?

To be more specific, I want to search a list, but each comparison is quite costly. I'd like to parallelize the search, but I'd like the rest of comparisons to be discarded once a match is found.

Answer (score 6):

Did you mean `fromMaybe` instead of `maybe`?

```
x `par` y `pseq` (fromMaybe y x)
```

Also you are creating a spark for evaluating `x`, not `y`. So `fromMaybe y x` will not be evaluated until `y` is evaluated. Probably you meant the opposite:

```
y `par` x `pseq` (fromMaybe y x)
```

If all above is true, then the answer to your question is "no", the spark will not be stopped when already started (though it will be discarded if not yet started.) You can check it with the following test:

```
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Parallel
import System.IO.Unsafe
import System.Mem

{-# NOINLINE x #-}
x = unsafePerformIO $ do
  threadDelay 1000
  return (Just 1)

{-# NOINLINE y #-}
y = unsafePerformIO $ do
  print "will eval y"
  threadDelay 3000000
  print "did eval y"
  return (2 :: Int)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ y `par` x `pseq` fromMaybe y x
  print "done"
  performGC
  threadDelay 4000000
```

The output:

```
"will eval y"
1
"done"
"did eval y"
```

Also you can check runtime statistics, `+RTS -s`. It contains a number of GC'd sparks.

Comment: Yes, you corrected my mistakes just as it should have been :), thank you! So I guess for terminating tasks I have to resort to using concurrency and manually killing threads with `killThread`.